# Moving Text inside of Button when onClick fired

Tags: android

I have a `TableLayout` with some a `TableRow` children that are `Button`s that contain some info.

When the `View.onClickListener` is fired, the gravity of the text inside `Button` changes from center to top. (Not in code, only visually). Also, clicking one `Button` changes the gravity of each `Button` after going back to the `Fragment` that holds the whole `View`.

**Here's my XML**

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonGrid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topbotLine"
    android:divider="@color/line_whieish" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/wwwButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/filter_button_click"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/www"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/details_normals_font_size" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/line_whieish" />
```

**Here's my Java**

```
    Button wwwBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wwwButton);
    if (annotationDetail.getData().getWww() != null) {
        wwwBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent wwwIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(annotationDetail
                        .getData().getWww()));
                startActivity(wwwIntent);
            }
        });
    } else {
        wwwBtn.setClickable(false);
        wwwBtn.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green_app_click));
    }
```

EDIT 2:

Adding selector:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/green_click"
    />

<item android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@color/green"
    />
```

Comment: Offtopic: don't use uppercase ids. use underscored versions like www_button

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with your layout, post the java code that is executed onClick.

Comment: Offtopic: will do, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @JakubW There's nothing wrong with using that naming convention for your id. [The system contains several that are lower camel case too](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/ids.xml)

Comment: @adneal cool, its much more clear to me to make ID's like that and XML names with underscores :)

Answer (score 0):

The `wwwBtn.setClickable(false);` part will change the applied theme. Check if that is your problem.

Comment: Hm, sorry, no idea then. There seems nothing wrong with your code/layout.

Comment: There must be something wrong or something that I've overlooked.
The problem is that we cannot see it :D I don't think its a BUG on Android side.

Comment: maybe check the `android:background="@drawable/filter_button_click"` ressource. I still think it's a style that has gone rogue :)

Comment: I've added my selector in EDIT 2. It does not look like it might have done anything bad. But would it be possible that background color change could change text gravity?

Comment: I don't think it can do that. Can't help you out with this one, sorry.